# Decompiled VB 6.0 Application Call Statement

Tags: decompilation, visual-basic

I decompiled a VB application using VB Decompiler pro. It contains the following call statements:

```
Call {EEF18FCD-D67D-4E3C-AA21EC9AF56F90E9}.Method_arg_B8 (global_248, CStr(var_98))
```

Can you please explain what does this call do?

Comment: The part `{EEF18FCD-D67D-4E3C-AA21EC9AF56F90E9}` seems to be a CLSID so it might refer to an ActiveX/COM object registered by the program. Therefore my guess would be that this is a method call on an COM object instance defined in an external DLL. If you have installed the program check your registry to which DLL the CLSID belongs to. You should find the details here `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{EEF18FCD-D67D-4E3C-AA21EC9AF56F90E9}`.

Comment: I checked the registry but could not find ```HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{EEF18FCD-D67D-4E3C-AA21EC9AF56F90E9}```. Then I tried to log the changes the program does to the registry upon installation. But these CLSIDs don't show up there too.

Comment: Try searching in regedit for that guid, it might be in HKCU or Wow64 part of HKCR